# using \nameref only if there is a name

Tags: macros, hyperref, cross-referencing

I am referencing some sections (actually those will be custom defined in the end) by number, type and name. But it happens that there is no name. So I want to leave it out. How can I test for that?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=darkred]{hyperref}
\newcommand\doubleref[1]{\autoref{#1} (\nameref{#1})}

\begin{document}

\section{This and That about Everything}\label{sec:thisthat}
    Some text.

\section{}\label{sec:two}
    Like meantioned in \doubleref{sec:thisthat} and \doubleref{sec:two}.

\end{document}
```

So in this example the second reference should automatically only be *section 2* and not *section 2 ()*.

I tried

```
\newcommand\doubleref[1]{\autoref{#1}\edef\nae@tmp{\nameref{#1}}\ifx\empty\name@tmp\relax\else\ (\name@tmp)\fi}
```

but `\nameref` does not seem to return an expandable version of the name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you say `\label{x}`, LaTeX stores the data in a macro called `\r@x`; the title (available when using `hyperref`) is the third of five token lists. In your case we want to test whether the title is empty, which means that the relevant token list contains only `\relax`, that `hyperref` always appends to the title.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=darkred]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\long\def\cana@extract#1#2#3#4#5{\unexpanded{#3}}
\def\cana@relax{\relax}
\newcommand\doubleref[1]{\autoref{#1}%
  \@ifundefined{r@#1}\relax{\edef\cana@temp{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\cana@extract\csname r@#1\endcsname}%
    \ifx\cana@temp\cana@relax\else~(\nameref{#1})\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{This and That about Everything}\label{sec:thisthat}
    Some text.

\section{}\label{sec:two}
    Like meantioned in \doubleref{sec:thisthat} and \doubleref{sec:two}.



\end{document}
```

I use `\edef`, but protecting the title with `\unexpanded`, so that it won't be expanded completely, which could cause big problems. This is tested only when the macro associated to the label has already been read in from the `.aux` file.

#### UPDATE

With a more recent LaTeX kernel, the code above no longer works, due to changes in the internal management of cross references.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=darkred]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\long\def\cana@extract#1#2#3#4#5{\unexpanded{#3}}
\newcommand\doubleref[1]{\autoref{#1}%
  \@ifundefined{r@#1}{\relax}{%
    \edef\cana@temp{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\cana@extract\csname r@#1\endcsname
    }%
    \ifx\cana@temp\@empty\else~(\nameref{#1})\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{This and That about Everything}\label{sec:thisthat}
    Some text.

\section{}\label{sec:two}
    Like meantioned in \doubleref{sec:thisthat} and \doubleref{sec:two}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: For whatever reason, this doesn't work for me while Heiko's solution does. I have no clue why.

Comment: @Piotr well, almost nine years passed since the answer was given. Why not asking before downvoting?

Comment: @Piotr I posted an updated version

Comment: Thanks, it works! 
I didn't expect such an old post to be fixed so I just wanted to push the working solution up. Also, I thought it's not a big deal - if an update comes, I can reverse the downvote and instead upvote this.

Comment: Actually, it compiles and seems to work but I get an error: ! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \edef \cana@temp.

Comment: It gives the error when I use it like this:
\begin{proof}[of \doubleref{my-big-theorem}]
\end{proof}
Yet, the output PDF seems to be correct. Strange.

Comment: @Piotr I tried it with `amsthm` and it works. Perhaps you have done something else, because `\begin{proof}[...]` doesn't automatically provide “Proof” in front of the text in the optional argument. I guess it deserves a new question.

Comment: Yeah, I did more than something, sorry for not reporting that before: my "proof" is really an instance of a theorem defined via thmtools with amsthm option. I guess taking \begin{theorem}[\doubleref{...}] with amsthm gives a MWO.

Answer (score 7):

Reimplementation of Gregorio's solution using package `refcount`.
`\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{name}{}` extracts the nameref part of the
reference `#1`. The command is full expandable. If there is not a name,
then the test becomes `\if\vcenter\vcenter`. Otherwise the name expands
to something non-expandable that differ from `\vcenter`. Instead of `\vcenter`
also other non-expandable tokens can be used, it should be a token that does
not occur at the start of a name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=darkred]{hyperref}

\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand*{\doubleref}[1]{%
  \autoref{#1}%
  \if\vcenter\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{name}{}\vcenter
  \else
    ~(\nameref{#1})%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section{This and That about Everything}\label{sec:thisthat}
    Some text.

\section{}\label{sec:two}
    Like meantioned in \doubleref{sec:thisthat} and \doubleref{sec:two}.

\end{document}
```

A variation, where the whole expression is made into a link:

```
\newcommand*{\doubleref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[{#1}]{%
    \autoref*{#1}%
    \if\vcenter\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{name}{}\vcenter
    \else
      ~(\nameref*{#1})%
    \fi
  }%
}
```