# Automatic referencing of item number in enumerate environment

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

Here is what I want:

[image]

And here is how I want to achieve this:

Just like you have the `\label` and `\ref` commands for automatic section number referencing, I wish to have **something similar which will auto-reference the specific item number (1.2.1 in my case) without me having me explicitly write it out every time**. This will be part of a big report I'm writing, hence I wish to make my work less cumbersome

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 1st item 
\begin{enumerate}[{1.}1]
\item 1st nested item
\item 2nd nested item
\begin{enumerate}[{1.2.}1]
\item Useful/Important Information
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\item 2nd item
\end{enumerate}

\noindent In this paragraph, I talk a bit about the Useful/Important Information and then reference the item number

\end{document}
```

Comment: Same `\label` and `\ref` works for this also.

Comment: @egreg, can you help me out again?

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks a lot. I wasn't aware of this. However, there seems to be some formatting issues with the printed label. It is getting displayed as 1(2)1. Why is this happening and how can I get around this?

Comment: That isn't the default formatting for an item reference, can you make a complete small document that shows the effect, you are probably loading a package that changes the way item labels are displayed without changing the way they are referenced.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done

Comment: oops  that's unfortunate. I can't _possibly_ blame it on the package you have loaded.

Comment: hmm the usage there is a bit strange as you are disabling latex's automatic numbering. Probably `enumerate` ought to be able to cope but it's a very old package (a lot older than latex2e). Rather than patch in a fix I think you should go with @HarishKumar's suggestion.

Comment: don't you like the existing answer? I could probably  patch enumerate but the code hasn't been touched since last millenium and the newer packages have more features.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry I overlooked Harish Kumar's answer. Thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: Maybe this could be interesting for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64521/10570

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am used to `enumitem` than `enumerate` as it is newer and offers much more customizations. As an additional tool, I suggest the use of `cleveref` for clever referencing as in this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} %% for effortless customization of enumeration
\usepackage{hyperref} %% Just to provide clickable links
\usepackage{cleveref} %% for clever referencing
\crefdefaultlabelformat{(#2#1#3)}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item{First item}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*]
    \item{First nested item}
    \item{Second nested item}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic*]
        \item{Useful/important information} \label{item:myitem}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
  \item{Second item item}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent In this paragraph, I talk a bit about the Useful/Important Information and then reference the item number~(\ref{item:myitem}).

In this paragragh, I talk and the point to some information given in~\cref{item:myitem} (Using cref)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sure `newer` is the word you meant to use rather than `better`. `enumerate` was one of my first packages don't be too hard on it!) (+1 from me, saves me fixing enumerate:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry yar, I didn't mean it. I am used to `enumitem`. Changing the answer immediately. `:-)`

Comment: Why the {} around the content of the items?

Comment: @Guido: Nothing special. I made it a personal preference to make it more readable. That is all.

Comment: @HarishKumar it might be more readable without (for example if the content is several lines), but again it is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 5):

`enumerate` is a very old package and probably as I mentioned in comments it is better to use a newer package these days as they offer more flexibility (`enumerate` is a lot older than the `keyval` package for example).  So you should probably not unaccept the other answer but for the record...

The easiest way to get this in latex doesn't involve using a package at all, or having to manually modify the item labels with optional arguments. Just declare the label counters to use the full dotted form rather than just the final numbers. (That is use a similar set of definitions as is usually used for sections and subsections)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\theenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}
\let\labelenumii\theenumii
\let\p@enumii\@empty
\renewcommand\theenumiii{\theenumii.\arabic{enumiii}.}
\let\labelenumiii\theenumiii
\let\p@enumiii\@empty
\makeatother

%opening
\title{}
\author{}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 1st item 
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1st nested item
\item 2nd nested item
\begin{enumerate}
\item Useful/Important Information\label{a}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\item 2nd item
\end{enumerate}

\noindent In this paragraph, I talk a bit about the Useful/Important Information and then reference the item number \ref{a}

\end{document}
```

If you do want to use the `enumerate` package and the markup you had, you need to make it use the full label as the reference not add a new (different) prefix.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\makeatletter

\def\thetolabel#1the{#1label}
\let\p@enumi\thetolabel
\let\p@enumii\thetolabel
\let\p@enumiii\thetolabel
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 1st item 
\begin{enumerate}[{1.}1.]
\item 1st nested item
\item 2nd nested item
\begin{enumerate}[{1.2.}1.]
\item Useful/Important Information\label{a}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\item 2nd item
\end{enumerate}

\noindent In this paragraph, I talk a bit about the Useful/Important Information and then reference the item number \ref{a}

\end{document}
```