# Create \ref for nested enumitem \item without nesting in the output

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, enumitem, nesting

Sorry the question is a bit awkward.

Basically I have nested `\begin{enumerate}` lists. I'd like something to appear like this:

```
1 Foo
 1.1 Bar
 Please see additional information in subsection 1
   1.1.1 Baz
```

But when I use this code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Foo
  \begin{enumerate}
     \item Bar
     Please see additional information in subsection \ref{test}
     \begin{enumerate}
       \item Baz
       \label{test}
     \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

It appears like this:

```
1 Foo
 1.1 Bar
   Please see additional information in subsection 1.1.1
   1.1.1 Baz
```

When the nesting gets heavy, it ends up looking a lot uglier ("see subsection 3(d)iC"). Is there a way to just list the final nesting level? I've tried to simplify my code to make it a bit easier to read. Hopefully it doesn't confuse the issue.

Comment: So you wish to keep the numbering of the `enumerate`, but only remove the hierarchy in the reference. Correct?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63953/extended-reference-for-enumerate-item-using-parent-environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) provides separate `label` and `ref` components to its lists. So, you could have a different representation of your reference to an item than the label that is set for that item. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*]
  \item Foo
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=(\alph*)]
     \item Bar
     Please see additional information in subsection \ref{test}
     \begin{enumerate}[label*=\roman*,ref=\roman*]
       \item Baz
       \label{test}
     \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Although I've defined the list construction together with its usage, this can be performed globally. See section **5 Global settings** (p 9) of the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

This also interfaces seamlessly with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Comment: This appears to be what I'm looking for. I can get the specific labels to work as you showed in this example, but I can't seem to get the global settings working? For instance:
`\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{label=\Roman}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Foo

\item Bar

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}`

Comment: That shows a list with Arabic numerals instead of Roman numerals as I'd expect.

Comment: I'm using version 2.2 of the `enumitem` package. Maybe that's the problem? That's what came with TeX Live for my Ubuntu distribution, but from the documentation it appears to be very old compared to the latest version.

Comment: @aardvarkk: The distribution on Ubuntu is notoriously out-of-date and yes, I would think that the outdated version of the package is the problem (it should be 3.5.2). See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1) and maybe [Where do I place my own `.sty` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](http://goo.gl/ByVnz) (in a pinch).

Comment: Hrm... since I'm on Ubuntu using Tex Live, I have no package manager like `tlmgr`. Instead, I tried to manually grab the new `enumitem.sty` file from CTAN and replaced my local copy. Now there's an error during compilation (`! Argument of \enit@refstar@i has an extra }.`). CTAN doesn't seem to list dependencies, and I'm assuming I now have some *other* package which is unmatched to this latest version of enumitem. No idea where to got from here. Anyway, your answer as you've posted it is correct, so thanks for your help!

Comment: Nevermind, I just needed to add a little `*` onto my `\Roman` and everything appears to be working great with the (now latest) version of `enumitem`. Great!

Comment: @aardvarkk Wow I was getting the same error. Google sent me to your comment. Thanks for replying with your solution! I have no idea how I missed that.

Answer (score 7):

Please always post complete documents not just fragments. You can redefine the prefix used at each level of list to be empty.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumi{}
\renewcommand\p@enumii{}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{}
\renewcommand\p@enumiv{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Foo
  \begin{enumerate}
     \item Bar
     Please see additional information in subsection \ref{test}
     \begin{enumerate}
       \item Baz
       \label{test}
     \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 This definitely gets me where I was headed, but I think @Werner has an answer which more closely matched my intent and feels a bit more clean (in my opinion). Thanks so much for your help!